# MYSQL sub-query from another table

Tags: mysql

i have this MYSQL statement:

```
SELECT r.id AS id, r.validSince AS validSince, r.validUntil AS validUntil, o.updatedTime as updatedTime, o.Owner AS Owner, fd.sid, fd.baseData
FROM #__sobipro_relations AS r 
INNER JOIN #__sobipro_field_data AS fd ON fd.fid="71" 
INNER JOIN #__sobipro_object AS o ON r.id=o.id 
WHERE r.oType="entry" 
AND o.approved=1 
AND o.state=1 
AND ((r.validSince<="2014-11-10T02:57:51-07:00") AND(r.validUntil>="2014-11-10T02:57:51-07:00" OR r.validUntil="0000-00-00T00:00:00")) 
GROUP BY r.id
```

I would now like to have the the query return only results that meet this criteria:    #__sobipro_field_data.baseData = 1002 (or some other number)

i tried to add     **AND fd.baseData=1002**   like this:

```
SELECT r.id AS id, r.validSince AS validSince, r.validUntil AS validUntil, o.updatedTime as updatedTime, o.Owner AS Owner, fd.sid, fd.baseData
FROM #__sobipro_relations AS r 
INNER JOIN #__sobipro_field_data AS fd ON fd.fid="71" 
INNER JOIN #__sobipro_object AS o ON r.id=o.id 
WHERE r.oType="entry" 
AND o.approved=1 
AND o.state=1 
AND fd.baseData=1002 
AND ((r.validSince<="2014-11-10T02:57:51-07:00") AND(r.validUntil>="2014-11-10T02:57:51-07:00" OR r.validUntil="0000-00-00T00:00:00")) 
GROUP BY r.id
```

But it doesn't work, it returns same results

any idea how to achieve this ?
Thanks

ok, so i was probably approaching this in the wrong way, i needed some kind of a sub-query to solve it. this worked

```
SELECT r.id AS id, r.validSince AS validSince, r.validUntil AS validUntil, o.updatedTime as updatedTime, o.Owner AS Owner
FROM j7v3x_sobipro_relations AS r 
INNER JOIN #__sobipro_object AS o ON r.id=o.id 
WHERE r.oType="entry" 
AND r.id IN (SELECT fd.sid FROM #__sobipro_field_data as fd WHERE fd.sid = r.id AND fd.baseData = 1002 )
AND o.approved=1 
AND o.state=1 
AND ((r.validSince<="2014-11-10T02:57:51-07:00") AND(r.validUntil>="2014-11-10T02:57:51-07:00" OR r.validUntil="0000-00-00T00:00:00")) 
GROUP BY r.id
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I think your issue is coming from the fact that you're joining to this `#__sobipro_field_data` only `fd.fid="71"` I guess all the results you're getting back are wrong.

Comment: Your query has GROUP BY r.id in it, but several of your returned fields are not directly dependent on r.id. Can you post some test data that demonstrates the problem you are having?

Comment: you don't have any relationship between your "r" alias and the "fd" alias and would otherwise create a Cartesian result.  Should there be something like an "r.id = fd.rid AND fd.fid = 71"?

Comment: ok, thanks for your help and giving me direction, i needed to use a subquery